# Redirect all http:// request to https://

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, http-request, redirection

Earlier i have posted this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104047/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https-on-magento but didn't get any reaction.

Here is my site URL : www.trendy-mode.nl
it will redirect you to : https://www.trendy-mode.nl/

Now problem is menu link or any other sub-links are not redirect with `https://`

EX: 
There is menu like - NIEUW | KLEDING | SCHOENEN | ACCESSOIRES etc.

If you click on NIEUW menu, a new page will be open but not redirect with `https://`

I have tried a lot .htaccess tweaks but not works. Anybody here to help me on this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Changing the unsecure base url to https will change all links and redirect non-https requests to https://example.com/ (the home page), because that's what Magento does when the base URL validation fails.

So this is a good start but to also redirect http://example.com/foo/ to https://example.com/foo/ you need to do it via webserver redirect.

For example, add the following code at the top of your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Or if you use a reverse proxy like Varnish:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This is because the requests from Varnish to Magento will be without SSL (HTTP), but Varnish sets the X-Forwarded-Proto header to "https" if the original request was made with SSL (HTTPS).

Comment: @Abhishek I just tested your site and since it's not working yet - Fabians instructions above are correct .. but should also say that these 2 lines should be added to .htaccess file in the root of your magento installation but NOT at the top (generally) but as mentioned below, just after `RewriteEngine On` . The way I have done it is just slightly different in that my second line reads; `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: Has anyone experienced adverse effects on google page rank after moving a magento site completely to https?

Answer (score 10):

For completeness we also do a very similar thing to what fschmengler has suggested with some additions;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

We place this inside the  section of the .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 9):

Set your base url for secure and unsecure in the backend.
Set yes on use secure url in frontend in the backend.

Then edit your app/etc/local.xml and include this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <frontend>
     <secure_url>
      <all>/</all>
     </secure_url>
   </frontend>
</config>
```

Or at least paste the XML tree frontend and lower in between the config tags.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I had set everything right but some urls were still using http instead of https.

Comment: i want to redirect specif url from https to http. so do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure `System > Configuration > Web > url_options > "Auto-redirect to Base URL = No"`. It was set to `yes`, and causing the problem.

Put below code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way would be to change the non-secure base url to https since magento then redirects all "non-secure" requests to this url and also generates the links with this url.

you can change the base url under system -> configuration -> general -> web

Comment: Thank you for your replay.. i did it but now if you open this link : www.trendy-mode.nl/damesschoenen/slippers it will jump you to homepage. have any solution?

Comment: hm thats weird :) Did you mind the trailing slash in the base url? I think this matter is really interesting as it will be most likely beeing seo relevant in the future (or maybe already now?) to have the whole page using https. I can ask my colleague tomorrow since he had done this for a magento shop already

Comment: although fschmengler's solution should work I think, the answer of @Michael seems like the right way to do this if it works

Comment: Well fschmenglers answer is not false. I am just annoyed of Magentos update strategy as it touches .htaccess and index.php but not local.xml. So it's more 'update save' imho

Answer (score 2):

The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) recommend against using a rewrite:

To redirect `http` URLs to `https`, do the following:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     Redirect / https://www.example.com/
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.example.com
     # ... SSL configuration goes here
 </VirtualHost>
```

This snippet should go into main server configuration file, **not** into `.htaccess` as asked in the question.

This article might have come up only after the question was asked and answered, but seems to be the current way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code at the top of the .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```