# How do I change all the http:// urls to // on my homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, url, ssl

I ran into trouble when I enabled SSL on my magento web store, my javascript console throws a mixed content exception since some contents of the pages are still requesting http:// protocol. I would like all my http:// urls to be switched over to // so my site can successfully load content from both protocols. Where in the magento file structure can I find the script that writes the protocal for javascript tags in the header of my homepage ?

Sorry for the noobish question as I am completely new to magento, any help would be appreciated

Comment: if your url is hardcoded, you have to change it in templates.

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from configuration: *System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure >  Base JavaScript URL* and *Base Skin URL*

Unfortunately you cannot change it to `//example.com/` because the form validation insists on a URL with protocol.

You can change the value directly in the database:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value='//example.com' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_js_url'
```

This works but then you can never save the "web" configuration form from the backend anymore.

It's probably better to just change the "unsecure" base URLs to "https" so that they always load with HTTPS.

Comment: thank you, I will try looking for base URLS and changing them one by one, also how much of a risk would it be if I set unsecure urls to https:// in System -> Configuration -> General -> Web ?

Comment: The only risk I am aware of is that if you use a Varnish cache in front of Magento you need additional SSL termination to be able to cache HTTPS URLs. This answer might also interest you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107083/redirect-all-http-request-to-https/107086#107086

Comment: oh I see, in case I want to manually change each header link to https would I find these hard-coded urls in my template file structure ?

Comment: There should not be any hard coded links, but if there are, you have to change them separately, yes