# Update Google Results to https

Tags: redirect, seo, https

My server manager updated our site to use https site-wide. Now all of our search results redirect to the home page. We don't want to lose our ranking, which is currently very high. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107086/26062

I added the following to .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, perfectly allowed by the agreements here.